# Pivot in PostgreSQL using with clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, unpivot

I need some help in writing the SQL query.

I want to convert

| Product | Employee | Sales | Sales_inUSD | Sales_inEuro |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Anand | 10000 | 121.24 | 114.26 |
| A | Yash | 12000 | 145.51 | 137.10 |
| B | Anand | 13000 | 157.64 | 148.37 |
| B | Yash | 15000 | 181.89 | 171.42 |

to

| Product | Anand | Yash | Currency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10000 | 12000 | Rupee |
| A | 121.24 | 145.51 | USD |
| A | 114.26 | 137.10 | Euro |
| B | 13000 | 15000 | Rupee |
| B | 157.64 | 181.89 | USD |
| B | 148.37 | 171.42 | Euro |

I have to achieve this using with clause,  I cannot make any kind of the table. and I have to do it in Postgresql where PIVOT/UNPIVOT doesn't work.

Comment: Why would you use the `WITH` clause? Isn't a `UNION` sufficient?

Comment: I tried UNION too but was unable to get the desired result. Can you help me with that? As I want to convert this UNPIVOT to PIVOT table

Answer (score 0):

UNPIVOT can be done by using a cross join with a VALUES clause:

```
select t.product, 
       t.employee,
       u.*
from the_table t
  cross join lateral (
    values ('Rupee', t.sales), ('EUR', t.sales_ineuro), ('USD', t.sales_inusd)
  ) as u(currency, sales)
;
```

Doing a PIVOT can then be done using conditional aggregation.

```
select t.product, 
       max(u.sales) filter (where employee = 'Anand') as anand,
       max(u.sales) filter (where employee = 'Yash') as yash,
       u.currency
from the_table t
  cross join lateral (
    values ('Rupee', t.sales), ('EUR', t.sales_ineuro), ('USD', t.sales_inusd)
  ) as u(currency, sales)
group by t.product, u.currency
order by t.product, 
         case u.currency
           when 'Rupee' then 1
           when 'USD' then 2
           else 3
         end
```

A common table expression isn't really necessary, but can be used if you want:

```
with unpivot as (
    select t.product, 
           t.employee,
           u.*
    from the_table t
      cross join lateral (
        values ('Rupee', t.sales), ('EUR', t.sales_ineuro), ('USD', t.sales_inusd)
      ) as u(currency, sales)
)
select product, 
       max(sales) filter (where employee = 'Anand') as anand,
       max(sales) filter (where employee = 'Yash') as yash,
       currency
from unpivot
group by product, currency
order by product, 
         case currency
           when 'Rupee' then 1
           when 'USD' then 2
           else 3
         end
```

Comment: Thankyou.. what does u.* mean... can you explain pls